# How to use combination of text and variables in NSString?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, variables, macos

How would I use a combination of text and variables in a NSString?
I know that in an NSLog, it looks like this:

> int number = 5; 
>   NSLog(@"My favorite number is %i", number);

How would I go about doing something like that in an NSString or even a char variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is fairly simple:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My favorite number is %i", number];
```

its basically the same as nslog.

Comment: This is just creating a variable not printing it on gdb, How this line of code is as similar as NSLog?

Comment: @krio The way it works is the same, except for the obvious differance of it printing to the console..  He asked about how to do the same to an NSString, which i showed him.

Answer (score 1):

`NSString * str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My favorite number is %i", number];`

if you just want to read about format specifiers, see: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Answer (score 0):

use all the power of old beloved printf formatting.

for objects "%@" will call the description method, so be smart to write this method for every custom class:

```
-(NSString*)description;
{
 NSString* result = [NSString stringWithFormat(@"%@" .......


}
```

for example:

```
-(NSString *)description;
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"is: %@ %@ %@ ; at: %f %f",
            name, address, img_name,
            coord.latitude, coord.longitude];
}
```